# Открыть программу через bat

Tags: bat

В операционной системе Windows создать командный файл с именем Modul_ВашаФамилия.bat, который выполнял следующие действия:
Выводил в первой строке текущую дату,
при вызове с параметром 1 – запускал программу Блокнот (Notepad.exe), 
при вызове с параметром 2 - запускал программу Калькулятор (Calc.exe), 
при вызове с любым другим параметром - фразу «такая команда не определена».

Comment: Рома, ну и? В чем проблема то?!

Comment: Лаба в ПТУ или на первом курсе универа?